# On Click command and not adding text when text box is blank

Tags: vba, ms-access

On Click I want my button to not add text when me.txtAddNote is blank and display a message prompting the user to enter text or cancel. And when me.txtAddNote has text I would like the On Click to enter the text. Currently, my code adds text on both conditions and even before the msgbox pops up. Any help is appreciated, thank you.

```
Private Sub cmdAddNote_Click()
Dim LName As String
On Error Resume Next
LName = DLookup("[LNAME]", "[qryEmpDepDes]", "[EMP_NO]='" & Me.txtUserID & "'")
[NOTES] = Date & ": " & Me.txtAddNote & " (" & Me.txtUserID & " " & LName & ")" & vbNewLine & vbNewLine & [NOTES]
Me.txtAddNote = ""
Me.cmdAddNote.Enabled = True
Me.cmdClose.Enabled = True
Me.cmdClose.SetFocus
'5-16-2016 testing blank text box'
  If Me.txtAddNote = "" Then
 If MsgBox("No text is entered. Hit OK to enter text. Hit CANCEL to close out.", vbOKCancel) = vbOK Then
    End If
Else
    DoCmd.Close
End If
```

End Sub

Answer (score 0):

Try checking the content of txtAddNote prior to anything else?

```
Private Sub cmdAddNote_Click()
Dim LName As String

If Me.txtAddNote.Text = "" Then
    response = MsgBox("No text is entered. Hit OK to enter text. Hit CANCEL to close out.", vbOKCancel)
    If response = vbOK Then
        ' do whatever you needed
    Else
        Exit Sub    ' Exit the sub if Cancel was clicked
    End If
End If

On Error Resume Next
LName = DLookup("[LNAME]", "[qryEmpDepDes]", "[EMP_NO]='" & Me.txtUserID & "'")
[NOTES] = Date & ": " & Me.txtAddNote & " (" & Me.txtUserID & " " & LName & ")" & vbNewLine & vbNewLine & [NOTES]
Me.txtAddNote = ""
Me.cmdAddNote.Enabled = True
Me.cmdClose.Enabled = True
Me.cmdClose.SetFocus

DoCmd.Close

End Sub
```